# Brownian Motion without path continuity assumption

Tags: stochastic-processes

I was reading this interesting discussion:
[Is the condition "sample paths are continuous" an appropriate part of the "characterization" of the Wiener process?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549570)
and feel some follow up questions might be interesting.

Basically, all the other conditions in a standard Brownian motion definition specify the "law", the distribution. Path continuity however, is something “extra”, it surely makes our life much easier, but somehow, I feel it is not “essential”, and I wonder whether properties of a standard Brownian motion also (in some way) hold for Brownian motion without path continuity assumption (Let’s call such process the Pre-Brownian motion below).

For example, in one link of the post quoted above, Byron has constructed an elegant counter example to show that, without the explicit path continuity assumption, a Pre-Brownian motion may have no continuous sample paths at all. But we also know that, a Pre-Brownian motion is a Martingale, therefore, almost surely all sample paths have left/right limits everywhere (I hope I get it right here…).

So a natural question will be:

Is it true that, the left and right limits are all the same a.s. for a Pre-Brownian motion?

For another question, let

$M_t(\omega) = \sup_{s\in [0\ t]} B_s(\omega)$.

For standard B.M., we can derive the distribution for $M_t$. But for a pre-Brownian motion, $M_t$ might not even be measurable. But how about a modified definition, an “essential supremum”, defined as:

$\tilde M_t(\omega) = \sup\{a | \mu(\{s | B_s(\omega)>a, s\in [0,t]\})>0\}$

where $\mu$ is the standard Borel measure. Will such a definition of $\tilde M_t$ measurable? Has a same distribution as $M_t$ in a standard Brownian motion?

We may also construct similar questions for hitting times for a Pre-Brownian Motion.

[EDIT] John answered the first question below.
For the second question about running maximum, I am still struggling with a reasonable defination. 
To avoid taking superimum over uncountable number of points in time (which always leads to question of measurebility), how about let's define the pre-Brownian motion on $\Bbb Q^+$ only? 
Now $M_t$ is measurable, and we can talk about its distribution. Will it be the same as in standard B.M.?

Comment: The very definition of your $\tilde M_t(\omega)$ is problematic, in that $s\mapsto B_s(\omega)$ need not be measurable.

Comment: You are right, perhaps we can try to use "outer measure" instead of Borel measure? but then I am not confident $\tilde M$ is measurable. Maybe it is hopeless here, because without some kind of path continuity, the sup operation consists of essentially uncountable number of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your first question, you overstate the case for right/left limits slightly.  Let's suppose that $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a pre-Brownian motion defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$. Then $B$ is indeed a martingale (with respect to its natural filtration). From this we know (thanks to Doob) that there exists $G\in\mathcal F$ with $\Bbb P(G)=1$ such that, for all $\omega\in G$,
$$
X_t(\omega):=\lim_{q\to t, q>t,q\in\Bbb Q}B_q(\omega)\qquad\hbox{ exists }\forall t\ge 0.
$$
(Let's define $X_t(\omega):=0$ for all $t\ge 0$ if $\omega\in G^c$.) The process $X$ so defined satisfies
$$
\Bbb P[X_t=B_t]=1,\qquad\forall t\ge 0.
$$
In particular, $X$ is also a pre-Brownian motion. Finally,
$$
\Bbb P[\{\omega: t\mapsto X_t(\omega) \hbox{ is continuous on }[0,\infty)\}]=1,
$$
so that $X$ is a Brownian motion.

The answer to your (revised) second question is YES, because for a standard Brownian motion $X$,
$M_t^X:=\max_{0\le s\le t}X_s=\sup_{0\le q\le t,q\in\Bbb Q} X_q$ by path continuity, and the stochastic processes $\{X_q:q\ge 0,q\in\Bbb Q\}$ and  $\{B_q:q\ge 0,q\in\Bbb Q\}$ (for $B$ the pre-Brownian motion) have the same distribution.

Comment: Thanks, I agree this addresses my first question. I added some thoughts about the running maximum, can you also take a look?